# Updating moment.js object within javascript object not updating value

Tags: javascript, object, momentjs, updating

I am creating a new Javascript object and passing the values into the constructor I would like the object to have. One value is a moment object (holding a date) I can see that the date is correct (2017-05-09) but the newly constructed object always has the value 2017-05-04. If I do a console.log on the attribute: object.start_date, then I am able to see the correct date, but if I do console.log on object, it shows the moment object with the wrong date 2017-05-04. I've tried updating in the constructor, manually doing an update on the object after creation, or by updating the value within the created object with a new instance function, but nothing changes the date. Here's some code/output.

Main question: Why is the moment object not being updating with the correct value I am giving it?

Thank you.
Function to create new route:

```
duplicateRouteSuccess(data) {
    let route = new Route(data['routeData']);

    route.changeStartDate(data['routeData']['starts_at']);
    console.log(route);
    console.log(route.starts_at);
    this.routeCalendar.scheduleRoute(route, route.repeats);
    this.close();
}
```

and the constructor:

```
  constructor (data) {
    this.id = data['id'];
    this.name = data['name'];
    this.starts_at = moment(data['starts_at']);
    this.repeats = data['repeats'];
    this.repeat_rate = data['repeat_rate'];

}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

doing JSON.stringify to my objects did show that they both have the same date, of 2017-05-08. But then my question is "when I access the attribute object.start_date to set the object onto a calendar, why does object.start_date say 2017-05-04"? Here is the stringify output image:[image]

**UPDATE 2**

The route.changeStartDate was just an instance function I created to attempt to update the "starts_at" field a second time since it did not appear to be updated in the constructor of the Route class. Here's the code for that:

```
changeStartDate(start_date){
    this.starts_at = moment(start_date)
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the codes instead of pictures?

Comment: as a side note, that console logs might be somewhat misleading, unless you totally understand the meaning of that small (i) sign next to the object. I suggest to try to use JSON.stringify in some parts of the object to verify the content of the object. Console log often shows the last content of the pointer, when you expand it.

Comment: added more code and removed some pictures @choz thanks for the pointer I will remember it in the future

Comment: @VladimirM I did as you suggested and updated my question. Thank you for pointing that out for me. Great advice I'll remember in the future when debugging. But now I'm still confused about why accessing the object after creation gives me the wrong date if the stringify version is correct.

Comment: what does changeStartDate do?

Comment: @VladimirM It was just an instance function I'd created to try to update the "starts_at" value a second time after I saw it wasn't updated in the constructor of the Route class.I updated the question with the code for it though